# Get list of all installed applications in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8.

I would like to get the list of installed applications in Windows Phone 8 using c#.

Though I get some samples in older versions I couldn't fetch in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Any detail of any sort would be very useful in providing a complete answer. Try to edit in some details and we can vote to re-open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality isn't available for 3rd party apps on Windows Phone 8. What exactly are you trying to do? You can pass along data using WP8's app2app functionality ([custom protocols for plain text and file extensions for file data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).

If you're interested in seeing this functionality in future WP versions please open up a new feature request on the [wpdev uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com) and ask that the Win8 [PackageManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240969.aspx) APIs be implemented.

Comment: If you are building company apps and are signing the apps with your company certificate, you can actually get a list of all installed company apps. So while this is not all apps, there is in fact an API for this. See InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. You can only access other applications that share (use DataTransferManager) and even then you are only sending data to other apps, not receiving data.