# How to get list of all installed applications in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nuget, windows-phone-8-emulator

Actually, I am working on windows phone 8 app. I want to show all installed apps(locally to that phone) to that user who runs this app. May be some nuget required. I could not use Package Class. please provide some code.

Comment: I doubt the OS will allow you to see what else is installed, when it doesn't even allow you access to the SD card.

Comment: not a duplicate. actually, i think that was about to get remotely but i need to show installed apps to the running user; not send this info to network

Comment: It is a dubplicate for sure. The accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599631/get-list-of-all-installed-applications-in-windows-phone-8 is the answer to your question as well. Quote: 'This functionality isn't available for 3rd party apps on Windows Phone 8. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's a duplicate. The questions are NOT for getting the list remotely, and the answers show that it isn't possible.

Comment: I tried the following code but "Package" showing namespace or reference error

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240969.aspx

Comment: That's because you cant use the `PackageManager` class. It's not available for Windows Store apps and not Windows Phone apps either http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx.