# windows phone check from web browser/javascript on web end if app is installed

Tags: c#, xaml, web, windows-phone-8, browser

If I click on a url on some 3rd party app `A` to open another app `B` (my app), it takes me to a web browser before redirecting to the app `B`.Is there any way to determine if the app `B` is installed on the windows phone device through javascript on the web end before trying to redirect to app `B`, given we have appId, device Id and Uri scheme name ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of all installed applications in Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599631/get-list-of-all-installed-applications-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: Not the duplicate. The question asks to determine app install status from the web browser ( and not from within the app ). Please read the question and its heading carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Nop. It is not allowed by the OS.