# Windows Phone: getting uri list of installed applications

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any way to get list of installed apps on the windows 8 phone ? If yes, kindly share the procedure or code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid this functionality isn't available to third party application developers quite yet. 
This is also a duplicate question.

A good answer is already provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13617515/404715